# Using C# API (2.0) doing upload returns "Metadata part is too large"

Tags: .net, youtube-api

using the Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest.Upload(Video v) api call then I get:

GDataRequestException with a response string "Metadata part is too large".

This direct upload call works on my personal development machine, but I get that exception  on our QA machine.

any ideas?

EDIT
here is the code:
so the only metadata that is added is title,description and tags (same metadata on both machines and same video).

```
           public void Add(InternalVideo video)
           {
           var youtubeVideo = ConvertVideo(video);
               var v = _request.Upload(youtubeVideo);
            }
    private Video ConvertVideo(InternalVideo video)
    {
        var youTubeVideo = new Video();

        youTubeVideo.Title = video.Title;
        youTubeVideo.Description = video.Description;
        AddTags(video, youTubeVideo);

        string contentType = MediaFileSource.GetContentTypeForFileName(video.URL);
        byte[] imageData = DownloadData(video.URL);
        File.WriteAllBytes(_tempVideoFileName, imageData);

        youTubeVideo.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(_tempVideoFileName, contentType);
        var link = new AtomLink("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads");
        link.Rel = ResumableUploader.CreateMediaRelation;
        youTubeVideo.YouTubeEntry.Links.Add(link);
        youTubeVideo.Private = false;

        return youTubeVideo;
```

}

```
    private void AddTags(InternalVideo video, Video youTubeVideo)
    {
        var category = video.Client.ClientSyndicationProviders[0].SyndicationProvider.Category;
        youTubeVideo.Tags.Clear();
        youTubeVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory(category, YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
        youTubeVideo.Keywords = video.Tags;
    }
```

EDIT 2:
This code works:
         _resumableUploader = new ResumableUploader(25);
         WebResponse r = _resumableUploader.Insert(_youTubeAuthenticator, youtubeVideo.YouTubeEntry);

I'm not sure why I had to use the resumeable uploader to make this work.
The only difference between machines is that that the QA machine is windows server 2003 R2,
while the development machine is a windows 7 professional.

Comment: Are you uploading a video with the same metadata in your development machine and in the QA machine? May be the metadadata is different in the QA machine? Can you publish the code and the data that you use in your QA machine?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (win 7 pro and server 2008) and got the same useless error message. I finally figured it out after writing the contents of the outputStream in GoogleApi\core\mediaservice.cs, EntrySend function, to a log file on my local machine and the server. I didn't have the mp4 file type I was trying to upload registered on the server. Once I registered the file type on the server it worked.

If anyone else needs to do this just find the file extension key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT on your client and right click it and click export. Then move the .reg file that's created to your server and double click on it to get the values added to your server. I also added the file type to the MIME Types in IIS but I don't think that was necessary, and I also recycled my app pool in IIS after I installed the registry key before testing it again.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me ... I added in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT .flv and .mp4, then i recycled application pool in IIS and worked !!! Thx